# What are some good reference materials in getting started with Visual Studio 2010 C++ for a mid-advanced C# dev?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I am a reasonably competent C# developer who has experience in threading, web development, windows client development, and basic (recent) experience in multi-platform C. I realize that there are questions out [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) that cover the insanely wide spectrum of C++.

Given that the C++ and Windows C++ realm is vast with a lot of legacy surface, what I am looking for are books, links, and media that provide a decent crossover point that discuss modern techniques, libraries, and Windows APIs for a seasoned dev (e.g., in what projects would I choose to use the MFC library?).

**Update**

Additional books that look interesting:

> [Windows System Programming (4th Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321657748)
>
> [The Old New Thing: Practical Development Throughout the Evolution of Windows](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321440307)
>
> [Programming Windows](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/157231995X)

**Update 2**

Looks like there is a good channel 9 video series that may become a good source of information as well.

> [Going Native (Blog)](http://www.gregcons.com/KateBlog/GoingNativeOnChannel9.aspx)
>
> [Channel 9 Video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/C9-GoingNative/GoingNative-0-Help-us-fly-this-plane-Some-modern-C-Meet-Ale-Contenti)

**Update 3**

> [C# to C++ - A Somewhat Short Guide](http://geekswithblogs.net/mikebmcl/archive/2012/02/02/c-to-c-ndash-a-somewhat-short-guide.aspx) by Michael B. McLaughlin

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. "When to use library X", or "how to use library y", or "how to learn C++" or "how to learn library z"? If you don't already know C++, isn't it jumping the gun a bit to start worrying about which Windows libs to use in your C++ code?

Comment: Everyone has to start somewhere. I'm looking for the zen of C++ development on the Windows platform so that I can, 1, narrow down what I want to learn, 2, see how seasoned C++ devs approach development on Windows, and 3, provide some context on what I already know of the Windows platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My list:

1. [MSDN - source of all dev information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/)
2. [Windows via C/C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735624240)
3. [Microsoft Visual C++ Windows Applications by Example: Code and explanation for real-world MFC C++ Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847195563) (will at least cover you e.g. question)

Comment: Awesome. I found CLR via C# very helpful so am excited about Windows via C/C++. Too bad amazon doesn't sell it anymore. :( "New from $350"? Haha. Looks like I can get it from the publisher though. Looks like "Windows System Programming" might be a good option as well. It has a good "Additional Reading" section: http://www.amazon.com/gp/reader/0321657748/ref=sib_books_pg?keywords=windows+via+c%2Fc%2B%2B&ie=UTF8